# Serving static files in flask with and without www subdomain?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask-based app on google app engine: http://gyroplane.io

Root domain is the app itself, subdomains like foobar.gyroplane.io are dynamic user-generated content.
Thus single Flask app is configured to catch both gyroplane.io and *.gyroplane.io requests and makes decisions on what to serve.

However, some people will likely type "www.gyroplane.io" in the browser and I want them to have exactly same experience as if they've typed "gyroplane.io".

To do that, I have to duplicate every routing rule for both top-level domain and the www. subdomain:

```
@root_app.route("/")
@root_app.route("/", subdomain='www')
def root_home():
    return render_template('admin/index.html', context=dict(
        SERVER_NAME=SERVER_NAME,
    ))
```

And also have to copy-paste the /static/ rule:

```
root_app.add_url_rule(root_app.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
                  endpoint='static',
                  view_func=root_app.send_static_file,
                  subdomain='www')
```

**Is there a not so hacky solution to tell Flask to treat two different subdomains as same?**

Comment: Sub-domains aren't part of the path.  They only determine how to browser got to the site.  You shouldn't have to deal with those rules at all ... or are you trying to implement different rules for the different subdomains on purpose?

Comment: Subdomains do get checked when matching is enabled. In the above example, my root_app.url_map has two entries for static files: ```<Rule 'www|/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>``` and when I skip the "www|" rule it returns 404 on every request to www. However, your comment got me thinking - since I already filter requests before they hit my apps, I can simply disable subdomain checking.